# Quotes are broken!

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

> [image]

It is quite recent (no longer than a day long), and it has affected only the quotes in the "bounty expires" notices.

Comment: damn I was going to add many exclamation marks in the title but they were removed :D

Comment: The system is smarter than you!!!!!!!! (oh, and you can use eeeeeeeeek if you want, but some devs don't like it ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please hold on as a fix is being pushed presently.

Comment: Is it heavy? I mean, in kg?

Comment: I see, you already pushed it. So its not heavy...

Comment: I am a strong developer, that's why I was hired...

Comment: You are not only strong, but also very brave. The Fix is actually very dangerous animal - I thought that you will go on it together, but you are *alone*? Impossible. ;)

Comment: Could be hilarious if it was "Please hold on as a &quot;fix&quot; is being &quot;pushed&quot; presently". :D

Comment: its a bug again.

Comment: This seems to be broken again: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8x3M4.png

Comment: I blame the localization fairy. In any case I'm committing a fix as I write

Comment: [Close, but no cigar](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gFGyM.png). Happens only on "bounty expiring soon" type, and only in the top bar, the email and global inbox are fine.