# HTML entities in "bounty expiring soon" notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications, html-entities

Although [Quotes are broken!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/241991/259867) and [Bug in HTML entities for badge notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242021/) both have [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), HTML entities still appear in "expiring soon" notifications:

[image: html]

Comment: Going to `&ldquo;look into this&rdquo;` now.

Comment: I alsk [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241991/quotes-are-broken) it, it was fixed and broken again somewhere near oct 27.

Comment: Not exactly the same. "bounty expiring soon" event was never fixed. Also, this got nothing to do with badges, tag removed.

Comment: I also reported this in a comment [on similar bug fix](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241991/quotes-are-broken#comment795105_241993), but it was utterly ignored, and I forgot to escalate it. :(

Comment: @nicael "expiring in one day" and "expiring soon" are two different events, with different code for each. The dev fixed only what you reported and never bothered with the others.

Comment: @TimPost The quote marks should have been around &ldquo;now&rdquo;

Comment: @Tim half year later, I guess it&#39;s impossible to fix? :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard Unless this is fixed in 6 days, you'll get HTML entities in a notification about this very bounty. :)

Comment: @2mkgz haha, two bugs one post! ;)

Comment: Looks fixed to me, @Sha?

Comment: @Oded yeah, waiting for you to post answer so I can give the 100 :-)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure when this was fixed or by whom, but it appears to have been fixed some time ago.

Probably coincided with some encoding fixed recently enacted by [balpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha).

Comment: Not you? Well, hope balpha will be kind enough to forgive you for stealing 120 (and counting) repz... ;)

Comment: He's a kind kind person. And lives in a different country.

Comment: To burninate your account he doesn't have to be anywhere near you, or the server... :P